# Is Boost ASIO post safe from a regular signal handler

Tags: c++, boost

Previously I was using a boost signal handler to perform closedown tasks, like so

```cpp
    asio::signal_set sig(srvs.get_boost_ios(), SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    sig.async_wait([&](error_code ec, int num) {
        if (!ec) {
            srvs.get_boost_ios().post([&]{
                srvs.close();
            }
        );
        }
    });
```

However, for certain configurations, the program should halt by itself. It wasn't doing so, because run does not return until everything is "done". Since we called sig.async_wait, there is still one more thing to do, so run() will not return until a signal has been handled.

So I changed the code to use std::signal, but still using Boost post:

```cpp
    // This may need to be extern "C" for portability
    static void signal_handler(int signal)
    {
        srvs.get_boost_ios().post([&]{
            srvs.close();
        });
    }
```

Is this safe? All of the actual work of closing down is being performed by Boost threads, and presumably the whole *point* of `post` is that it can be called asynchronously. But, does *can be called asynchronously* extend to *can be called from a signal handler*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `io_service::stop` to interrupt `io_service::run`.
As for manual signal handler, only [async-signal-safe functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) are safe to be invoked from there. The usual approach is to manually install signal handler (along with signal blocking / masking boilerplate) that will set global atomic variable and then to run io loop items one by one checking that variable on each iteration or to install periodic timer that will check that variable and stop io service.

Comment: `boost::asio::io_context::post` is not async-signal-safe then?

Comment: `boost::asio::io_context::post` is definitely not async-signal-safe, it allocates memory and may even throw an C++ exception.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [very small (non-portable) list of async-safe standard library functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Everything else is unsafe. This is exactly why you want `signal_set`.

If you don't want to continue waiting for a signal, just use `signal_set::cancel`. You can also bring out the big gun and call `io_context::stop()` but I don't recommend it: It's a better practice to implement graceful shutdown. You might always observe some timeout and issue `io_context::stop()` after a given time in systems where external factors might make shutdown take a long time/block.

Comment: Thanks, though in order to call `signal_set::cancel` I need to know that I'm finished, and if I've used signal_set then the IO context never finishes so it's a bit circular. I'm pretty sure I need something external to the IO Context, as I've now illustrated in my answer.

Comment: `io_context::stop()` is a graceful shutdown, it is actually called internally all the time, even when `io_context::run()` returns when it runs out of things to be dispatched.

Comment: @user7860670 That's the opposite of all the time, IMHO. It's not graceful shutdown at the application level (none of the completions run, giving the application no good space to respond to various cancellations, which ties into to resource management. Of course you **might** not need that, and rely on C++ lifetime management to "eventually" cleanup, but many applications have more needs, if only for diagnostics, logging and bookkeeping). There's a reason I mention it: It **can** be used, and I usually do, as a fallback for unforeseen/rare circumstances, like a stuck IO to network filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really in the comment from user7860670

> `boost::asio::io_context::post` is definitely not async-signal-safe, it allocates memory and may even throw an C++ exception.

I've added my own answer to share my code.

In main.cpp

```cpp
    // My object that uses boost::asio
    static auto srvs = services{};
    static std::atomic<bool> finished;
    static std::atomic<bool> signal_detected;

    extern "C" void signal_handler(int signal); // -W-missing-declarations
    extern "C" void signal_handler(int signal)
    {
        signal_detected = true;
    }
```

Which should all be signal safe. Then we can just poll for `signal_detected` in a non-boost thread.

```cpp
    static void handle_signal_detect()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;

        while (!finished)
        {
            if (signal_detected)
            {
                srvs.close();
                break;
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
        }
    }
```

Then in main install the signal handlers, start the thread and run the object

```cpp
    std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    std::signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);
    std::thread sigdet(handle_signal_detect);

    srvs.run();
    finished = true;
    sigdet.join();
```

If Boost ASIO runs out of things to do, srvs.run() returns. If a signal is caught, srvs.close() is called which posts a shutdown, causing srvs.run() to return.

Comment: I might be missing something, but couldn't you equivalently do this from within the `signal_set` completion handler?

Comment: There are two ways the program can terminate. Either it runs out of things to do, (when configured for client tasks) or it is stopped by a signal (when configured as a server).  If I use `signal_set` then the `iocontext` doesn't run out of things to do until a signal actually arrives, which doesn't suit client mode. I would need a different method of determining that all the work was done and then cancel `signal_set`. That's not unreasonable, but, it just didn't really match the path I had already set off on.